# In what chapter the 14th Noah have its first appearance?

Tags: d-gray-man

I am currently reading *D.Gray-man*. I have heard about the 14th Noah. I was wondering when he/she will appear. I am at chapter 145, how close am I to the appearance, or does the 14th Noah even appear?

Comment: I dropped the series a few years ago (when the chapter releases became highly irregular) so I've only read up to chapter 218. I do know who the 14th is and I have seen his appearance. But I can't really say more than this without revealing any major spoilers.

Comment: I found it its chapter 198